# Suspend Coroutine Hangs

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to get a deeper into coroutines. I have a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` that is supposed to fetch a network response. I can see in Charles that the network call is dispatched and returns successfully. However, my app just hangs on the network request line.

```
private suspend fun fetchVisualElementsFromServer(clubId: String): VisualElements {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        visualElementsService.fetchVisualElementsForClub(clubId)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<ResultVisualElements> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ResultVisualElements>,
                    response: Response<ResultVisualElements>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        response.body()?.let {
                            if (it.result == RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                       saveVisualElementsResponseInSharedPreferences(it.visual_elements)
                                cont.resume (it.visual_elements)
                            } else {
                                cont.cancel()  //edit
                            }
                        } ?: cont.cancel() //edit
                    } else {
                        cont.cancel(IOException("${response.code()}: ${response.errorBody()}"))
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResultVisualElements>, t: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(t, "visual elements fetch failed")
                    cont.cancel() // edit
                }
            })
    }
}
```

This where it hangs:

VisualElementsService.kt

```
fun fetchVisualElementsForClub(clubId: String): Call<ResultVisualElements> {
    return dataFetcherService.getVisualElementsForClub(clubId)
}
```

What am I missing here? I tried to make the `fetchVisualElementsForClub()` a suspend function, but that just makes the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` throw a `Suspension functions can only be called within coroutine body` error. But I thought that his was within a coroutine body?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT

I response to Rene's answer below, I want to add a few things.

You are right, I am missing three cont.cancel() calls. I've modified the OP. Good points.

I have breakpoints all over the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` such that any possible scenario (success, failure, etc.) will be hit. But that callback *never* registers.

Wondering if there is something missing in `fetchVisualElementsForClub()` that is needed to pass the callback up to the `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. That seems to be where this is hanging.

Comment: What version of kotlinx-coroutines-core do you use? Your code does not compile with e.g. 1.2.0 which has the following signature for resume: `CancellableContinuation.resume(value: T, onCancellation: (cause: Throwable) -> Unit)`. Maybe you have encountered a bug in earlier versions of that library that is fixed in later versions; try adapting to and upgrading to the latest version of this library.

Comment: 1.3.0. And I assure you, my code compiles and the app runs. At least up to the point where it hangs. :-)

Comment: Weird that it compiles for you, because I can reproduce the compilation error in the Kotlin Playground: https://pl.kotl.in/xlX8nRuAK

Answer (score 2):

You must call `cont.resume()` or `cont.cancel()` on every branch in your callback handling.
But in your example at least three cases are missing.

1. If the response is successful but no body is provided, you call nothing.
2. If the response is successful, the body is not null, but the `it.result` is not `RESULT_SUCCESS` you call nothing.
3. If something goes wrong in `onFailure`, you call nothing.

As long as neither `resume` or `cancel` is invoked, the coroutine will stay suspended, means hangs.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Please see the edit that I made to the OP. Is there something that I need to add to the VisualElementsService method to pass the callback up to the suspendCancellableCoroutine?

Answer (score -1):

when you use suspend keyword your are telling that function shoud be called inside a coroutine bode, for example:

```
suspend fun abc(){
   return
}
```

when you want to call above function you have to call it inside coroutines such as below:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
  abc()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I do that with a cancellable coroutine? That's the issue that I am trying to solve.